# Reduce time processing merging tables and dictionaries Python

Tags: python

Here I have the dictionaries:

```
dict_assembly = {'ind1gene1':'individual1', 'ind1gene2':'individual1','ind1gene3':'individual1', 'ind2gene1':'individual2', 'ind2gene2':'individual2','ind2gene3':'individual2', 'ind3gene1':'individual3', 'ind3gene2':'individual3','ind3gene3':'individual3','ind4gene1':'individual4','ind4gene2':'individual4','ind4gene3':'individual4','ind4gene4':'individual4'} 

dict_bhit = {'ind1gene1':'AAAAA', 'ind1gene2':'BBBBB','ind1gene3':'CCCCC', 'ind2gene1':'AAAAA', 'ind2gene2':'BBBBB','ind2gene3':'BBBBB', 'ind3gene1':'AAAAA', 'ind3gene2':'BBBBB','ind3gene3':'CCCCC','ind4gene1':'AAAAA','ind4gene2':'BBBBB','ind4gene3':'CCCCC','ind4gene4':'DDDDD'}

dict_identity = {'ind1gene1':'98','ind2gene1':'96','ind3gene1':'95','ind4gene1':'96','indi5gene1':'94','ind1gene2':'67','ind2gene2':'76','ind3gene2':'80','ind4gene2':'77','ind5gene2':'76','ind1gene3':'98','ind2gene3':'97','ind3gene3':'96','ind4gene3':'96','ind4gene4':'40'}

data = {} # temporary dictionary
```

The codes used for this example are split into two blocks.

First part:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    start = time.time()
    matrix_file = open("concatenated.matrix", "w" )
    col_subject = ['query', 'subject']
    df_accession = pd.DataFrame(dict_bhit.items(), columns=col_subject)
    col_genome = ['query', 'genome']
    df_assembly = pd.DataFrame(dict_assembly.items(), columns=col_genome)
    df_assembly['subject'] = df_assembly['query'].map(df_accession.set_index('query')['subject'])
    matrix = pd.get_dummies(df_assembly.set_index('genome')['subject']).max(level=0).max(level=0, axis=1)
    matrix.to_csv(matrix_file, sep='\t', header=True, index=True)
    print matrix
    end = time.time()
    print 'This step spent',round(end - start, 4), 'seconds\n'
```

Second part:

```
start = time.time()
matrix_file = open("identity.matrix", "w" )
col_bhit = ['gene', 'subject']
df_bmatch =  pd.DataFrame(dict_bhit.items(), columns=col_bhit)  # convert "dict_bhit" into a dataframe
col_file = ['gene', 'assembly']
df_origin = pd.DataFrame(dict_assembly.items(), columns=col_file)   # convert "dict_assembly" into a dataframe
col_percent = ['gene', 'percent']
df_percent = pd.DataFrame(dict_identity.items(), columns=col_percent)   # convert "dict_bhit" into a dataframe

for k, col in dict_assembly.items():
    if k in dict_bhit and k in dict_identity:
        data.setdefault(dict_bhit[k], {})[col] = dict_identity[k]
    elif k in dict_bhit and k not in dict_identity:
        data.setdefault(dict_bhit[k], {})[col] = "NA"
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(matrix_file, sep='\t', header=True, index=True)
print df

end = time.time()
print 'This step spent',round(end - start, 4), 'seconds\n'
```

Any suggestion about how to reduce the processing time to generate the second table? As you can see, the values of times are different in 2 fold.

```
Saving presence/absence table ...
             AAAAA  BBBBB  CCCCC  DDDDD
genome                                 
individual1      1      1      1      0
individual2      1      1      0      0
individual3      1      1      1      0
individual4      1      1      1      1
This step spents 0.0084 seconds

Saving identity table...
            AAAAA BBBBB CCCCC DDDDD
individual1    98    67    98   NaN
individual2    96    76   NaN   NaN
individual3    95    80    96   NaN
individual4    96    77    96    40
This step spents 0.0106 seconds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem and rest some few seconds in a large dataset I commented two lines at the "elif" (Option 1).

Option 1:

```
for k, col in dict_assembly.items():
    if k in dict_bhit and k in dict_identity:
        data.setdefault(dict_bhit[k], {})[col] = dict_identity[k]

    #elif k in dict_bhit and k not in dict_identity:
        #data.setdefault(dict_bhit[k], {})[col] = "NA"

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(matrix_file, sep='\t', header=True, index=True)
print df
```

For a small dataset you can use Option2 removeing directly the "if"condition.

```
Option 2:
for k, col in dict_assembly.items():

    data.setdefault(dict_bhit[k], {})[col] = dict_identity[k]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(matrix_file, sep='\t', header=True, index=True)
print df
```